# Offset a pointer to a pointer with a count variable

Tags: c, pointers

So currently I am working with a number of structures, pointers and the malloc function. As it stands I have structure which, amongst other variables, it holds a pointer to some memory space allocated using the malloc function.

I am using this space to store samples and therefore I am using a simple count variable to track how many samples there are. Now my difficulties arise from interfacing with my I2C function, which uses a triple pointer (signed char***) to store the data.

To handle this I use a double pointer (signed char**) to point to the memory space offered from the pointer in the structure and then I use the count variable to shift this pointer.

What I am finding is that the addition of the offset is simply incrementing from the memory where the initial pointer is kept.

The line of code I try to achieve this in is below.

```
signed char** VAL_PTR = ((signed char**)(&mem.Accel.xBase)) + ((signed char) mem.Accel.SampleCount);
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*which uses a triple pointer (signed char\*\*\*)*" <- don't be a [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). In fact, the single line of code you present looks overly complex. Maybe make yourself familiar with the strict aliasing rule, in any case, **start over** by first designing your data structures and program flow, and aim for a **simple** design.

Comment: We need to see a complete (but minimal) example that shows the types of all variables, and explains what the expected result is and what you get instead. Showing with code is better than showing with words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `xBase` is a pointer, a pointer to `xBase` (i.e. `&xBase`) is basically equivalent to a pointer to the first element of an array of one element of pointers. In your case `&xBase` is basically equivalent to the type `signed char *[1]`.

I.e. it looks something like this

```
+-------+
| xBase |
+-------+
^
|
&xBase
```

Now if you remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. If we substitute in `&xBase` and `SampleCount` then what you have is `*((&xBase) + SampleCount)` which is equal to `(&xBase)[SampleCount]`, which is element number `SampleCount + 1` of an array of *one* element. It will be out of bounds.

The above "image" with your addition will be something like

```
+-------+
| xBase |               ???
+-------+
^                        ^
|                        |
&xBase                   &xBase + SampleCount
```

Comment: In short I guess I'm asking if I can add an offset to the address pointed to by xBase when assigning to the pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @A.Derby In short, no. `&xBase + SampleCount` doesn't point anywhere valid. But you can do `xBase + SampleCount` of course, it's simply the same as `&(xBase[SampleCount])` (which means the value in `SampleCount` needs to a valid index). ***However*** the casting doesn't seem correct, unless each element in the memory pointed to by `xBase` *is* a pointer.

Comment: Ah right fantastic this has worked exactly as desired!

I used the type cast to allow pointer compatibility.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just to add some additional clarity I have now altered my approach. 

To obtain the address of where I need to write a sample to I use

`signed char* myPtr = mem.Accel.xBase + mem.Accel.SampleCount; `

I thought I required the level of indirection to gain access to the address of the memory location to write too. This wasn't the case!

There was also an issue with the previous solution which I haven't totally figured out but it does correspond with the type casting I was also using. 

Thanks again for the help!